# Given $x^2 - y^2 = 9$ and $xy = 3$. Find $x + y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hi can someone help me with this?

Given $x^2 - y^2 = 9$ and $xy = 3$. Find $x + y$

My solution:
\begin{align*}
x^2 - y^2 = 9 & \Longleftrightarrow (x^2 - y^2)^2 = 81\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^4 - 2x^2y^2 + y^4 = 81\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^4 + y^4 = 99\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^2 + y^2)(x^2 - y^2) = 99
\end{align*}

Since $x^2 - y^2 = 9$, it results that $9(x^2 + y^2) = 99$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 11$.

Gathering all previous results, one has that
\begin{align*}
2x^2 = 20 & \Longleftrightarrow (x = \sqrt{10})\wedge(y = 1)
\end{align*}

The answer on this site is different from mine : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmeBSRo9HQ4

Could someone pls explain this? Thanks

Comment: $x^4 + y^4 \neq (x^2 + y^2)(x^2 - y^2).$

Comment: Adding to the previous comment(s): $a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)$ always holds true. Unless $b=0$, $a^2+b^2\not=(a-b)(a+b)$.

Comment: Oh i see. So I was wrong because they didn't specify If x or y = 0 or not is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the polynomial identity $$(x+y)^4=(x^2-y^2)^2+4 x y (x+y)^2$$

Call $z = (x+y)^2$ and use $x^2-y^2 =9$, $x y=3$ to get
$$z^2=9^2+4\cdot 3\,z$$

Solve for $z$ to get $$z = \frac{12\pm\sqrt{12^2+4\cdot 81}}{2} = 6 \pm 3\sqrt{13}$$

Discard the negative solution since $z = (x+y)^2 \ge 0$, so $z = 6+3\sqrt{13}$.

Then $x+y = \pm \sqrt{z} = \pm\sqrt{6+3\sqrt{13}}$

Comment: This method is personally the easiest to understand for me and yeah great job thanks! Nice to see how you work backwards to obtain the answer easily.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Here is another way to approach it for the sake of curiosity.

Since $xy = 3$, we conclude that $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Based on such relations, we can divide both sides of $x^{2} - y^{2} = 9$ by $xy$ and make the change of variables $t = \dfrac{x}{y}$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^{2} - y^{2}}{xy} = \frac{9}{3} & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{x}{y} - \frac{y}{x} = 3\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow t - \frac{1}{t} = 3\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow t^{2} - 3t - 1 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow t = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{13}}{2}
\end{align*}

Consequently, one has the following collection of systems of equations to solve:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
xy = 3\\\\
\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{3 + \sqrt{13}}{2}
\end{cases}\quad
\begin{cases}
xy = 3\\\\
\dfrac{x}{y} = \dfrac{3 - \sqrt{13}}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

**EDIT**

Observe the second system of equations has no solution, because $xy = 3 > 0$, and $\dfrac{x}{y} < 0$.

Hence it suffices to consider the first system of equations.

If we multiply both of them together, we get
\begin{align*}
x^{2} = \frac{9 + 3\sqrt{13}}{2} & \Longleftrightarrow x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{9 + 3\sqrt{13}}{2}}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-9 +3\sqrt{13}}{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: is it ok if you could show how we get x + y? I am a bit confused

Comment: @EternalBlade sure, I am going to edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah coz I can't get the answer

Comment: @EternalBlade I have edited it. You can compare my solution with RobPratt's development.

Comment: Ok thanks for the solution. It's the same with RobPratt's answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is a more straightforward approach than the video, but it gives the solution in a different form.
Substitute $y=3/x$ to obtain $x^2-(3/x)^2=9$.  Multiply both sides by $x^2$, yielding $x^4-9=9x^2$.  Rewrite as $(x^2)^2-9x^2-9=0$, and apply the quadratic formula to obtain
$$x^2 = \frac{9\pm3\sqrt{13}}{2}.$$
Because $x^2 \ge 0$, you can discard the extraneous solution, leaving
$$x^2 = \frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2},$$
which implies that
$$x = \pm \sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}.$$
Now $$y = \frac{3}{x} = \pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{6}{3+\sqrt{13}}}
\cdot \sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{13}}{3-\sqrt{13}}}
= \pm \sqrt{\frac{6(3-\sqrt{13})}{9-13}}
= \pm \sqrt{\frac{-9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}
,$$
and so
$$x+y=\pm \left(\sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{-9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}\right).$$

---

To see that this solution matches the video, you can square both sides to obtain
\begin{align}
(x+y)^2 
&= \left(\sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{-9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2} + \frac{-9+3\sqrt{13}}{2} + 2\sqrt{\frac{9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{-9+3\sqrt{13}}{2}} \\
&= 3\sqrt{13} + \sqrt{(9+3\sqrt{13})(-9+3\sqrt{13})} \\
&= 3\sqrt{13} + \sqrt{-81+117} \\
&= 3\sqrt{13} + 6,
\end{align}
so
$$x+y = \pm \sqrt{6+3\sqrt{13}}.$$

Comment: Yeah good solution as well thanks! Nice to see how you work backwards to obtain the answer in such a neat way